# SQL select string with and without apostrophe

Tags: sql, mysql, database

So, i have a DB like this

> id | name
>
> 1  | students
>
> 2  | stu'dents
>
> 3  | student's

If i need to search 'students' should have all 3 results, ignoring the apostrophes in the database

I tried something like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE name ILIKE 'students'`

But I only have one result, because the search doesn't ignore the apostrophes from the database.

And I tried with:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE REPLACE(name, "'", "") ilike 'students'`

But return error: column "'" does not exist

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please don't tag spam. MySQL and PostgreSQL are two totally different RDBMSs, with different syntax and functionality. Use only the tag for the database you're actually using, and remove the other one. Posting with an invalid tag wastes both your time and ours, as people can write an answer only to find out that it won't work for the DBMS you're actually using. Tag spamming is a good way to quickly get your post closed or downvoted. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Could you please check this? it's working for me.

```
DECLARE @tableStudent TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @tableStudent 
VALUES('students'),
('stu''dents'),
('student''s')

SELECT * FROM @tableStudent
WHERE REPLACE(Name,'''','') LIKE '%students%'
```

Result

[image]